# How to extract an XML value from sibling element using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, scripting

I have an XML file structured like this:

```
<document>
    <Asset>
        <PropertyList Type="DataSource">
            <Property Name="one" Value="some_value1" />
            <Property Name="two" Value="some_value2" />
            <Property Name="three" Value="some_value3" />
        </PropertyList>
        <PropertyList Type="DecisionMaker">
            <Property Name="four" Value="FALSE" />
            <Property Name="five" Value="FALSE" />
            <Property Name="six" Value="FALSE" />
        </PropertyList>
    </Asset>
    <Asset>
        <PropertyList Type="DataSource">
            <Property Name="one" Value="some_value6" />
            <Property Name="two" Value="some_value7" />
            <Property Name="three" Value="some_value8" />
        </PropertyList>
        <PropertyList Type="DecisionMaker">
            <Property Name="four" Value="TRUE" />
            <Property Name="five" Value="FALSE" />
            <Property Name="six" Value="FALSE" />
        </PropertyList>
    </Asset>
</document>
```

In reality the document contains dozens of  elements and is created by another system. 
I'd like to construct a powershell script that will search the document for a Property Name of "four" with a value of "TRUE", then output the value of Property Name "Two" that exists under it's sibling element within the same Asset parent.

I am able to search through each Property node equaling name of "four" and value of "true" but I don't know how to get the value from a sibling element:

```
[XML]$Test = Get-Content ("C:\folder\test.xml")
$Test.SelectNodes("//Property") | % { $_ | ?{ ($_.Name -eq "four" -and $_.Value -eq "TRUE") }} | Select $_.Value
```

Could anyone offer any guidance?

Comment: There's probably some nice xpath way with select-xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ParentNode` attribute to go up a level from the **four** node then search for a **two** node child.

```
[XML]$Test = Get-Content ("C:\folder\test.xml")
$PropertyFourNode = $Test.SelectNodes("//Property") | % { $_ | ?{ ($_.Name -eq "four" -and $_.Value -eq "TRUE") }} 

$PropertiesNode = $PropertyFourNode.ParentNode
$PropertiesNode.Property | Where Name -eq 'Two'
```

Comment: Thank you! The .ParentNode was what I needed. The above solution didn't quite work, as I needed to use $PropertiesNode.ParentNode.PropertyList.Property to traverse up the tree but it helped me achieve what I was looking for.